# Why is sed not extracting value?

Tags: regex, sed

When I run my regex with sed

```
echo "abc-def-stg" | sed -e '/(\w*$)/g'
```

on regexr.com it works with no problems, but when I try to extract the value stg using said it does not work.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: There are two fundamental problems: 1. sed has its own programming language and requires more than just a regex. 2. "regex" is like "object oriented" in that it's a general concept with a bunch of different languages to express it. regexr defaults to JSRE and also supports PCRE, sed's programming language allows you to embed BRE (and ERE with `-E`).

Comment: `echo "abc-def-stg" | sed 's/.*-\(.*\)/\1/'` will do what you need. Or `awk -F'-' '{ print $3; }'`

Comment: Simpler: `echo "abc-def-stg" | sed 's/.*-//'`

Comment: Very few versions of sed or other command line tools will have any clue what `\w` means. Maybe you meant `[[:alnum:]_]`? There's also no brackets `()` in your input string so it can't match them in your regexp. Maybe you wanted to create a capture group `\(...\)` but then you don't have any backreference to it in the replacement text. Actually you don't even have replacement text. `man sed`.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is used to **replace** strings. You are trying to extract.

Use (as [John1024 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408391/why-is-sed-not-extracting-value#comment97537428_55408391))

```
echo "abc-def-stg" | sed '/.*-//'
```

It will remove all up to and including the last hyphen. Or

```
echo "abc-def-stg" | grep -oE '[^-]+$'
```

It will extract all characters other than a hyphen at the end of the string.